# Page not found in wordpress localhost

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have installed Wordpress on my localhost, no links are working. I get **page not found**.

What can I do ?

Using `.htaccess` like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /akclinics/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /akclinics/ [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: try going to settings-> permalinks and click save. If the problem is in htaccess and permalinks  this should fix it.

Comment: Hi nick , i m not able to open wp admin it redirectly shows page not found error what to do ?

Comment: What is the url of your wordpress installation? If you have access to your wordpress database then check wp_options table and find site_url and home_url and check if they are entered correctly. They should point to correct wordpress location. Also, try making backup of your htaccess and remove it from the root

Comment: Thnks nick its working fine now !!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

If you not able to go /wp-admin just open your database then

```
Your database-> wp-options table->wp-options->site-url->check and change it.
```

After Follow this steps once:

This may be caused by the permalink or .htaccess

- Go to settings-> permalink-> set it as default ->Reload or refresh
- Then again now Go to settings-> permalink->postname
- Your .htaccess will get update with the permalink.

Comment: why would you need to change site url in database manually on a fresh wordpress installation?

Comment: @ksno Actually we don't need to change the site url. But it may happens when we change in dashboard settings-siteurl-some different url .  May be she changed like that way.